Woocommerce admin order list billing and shipping field in uppercase
Hello I have used the following and added in Appearance - custom CSS
#billing_first_name, #billing_last_name, 
#billing_city, #billing_address_1 { 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
}

And in my checkout page when a client fills the field all becomes uppercase as you see in the screenshot:

But when the orders comes to admin,the fields are again lowercase as you see here:



What can I do so it will appear in admin orders also with uppercase letters? I dont know how to add the same  CSS on my admin orders.
Because I am newbie, could you please tell me how to add to admin the same css?
I tried to paste the same css in admin but didnt work.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Seems like you aren't selecting the right HTML elements on the admin page. You haven't provided the HTML code for the admin page (I imagine you can't since you are using WordPress), so I can't tell you exactly what CSS selector to use, but I can give you the general idea of what you want.
When you create a CSS rule, you have 2 parts: a selector and a list of CSS properties you want to apply to the HTML elements that match the selector given, in the following format:
selector {
  properties list
}

Based on this definition, you can determine that you want to keep the same CSS properties list that you already have (text-transform: uppercase;) and we only need to focus on the selector.
Determining what the selector should be is a bit harder, but not too much so. On your admin page, you should add a class to anything you want to have capitalized text. See this to learn how to add classes to elements in WordPress. In the example I give below, the class is capital-text:


.capital-text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>CSS Selector Practice</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>I am not capitalized.</p>
<p class="capital-text">I am capitalized.</p>
<p class="capital-text">I am also capitalized.</p>
</body>



